# Ломается кодировка при большом количестве символов в названии вложения

Tags: lua

Есть скрипт (не мой), который обрабатывает письмо поступившее в ящик - он вытаскивает из письма вложения и прикрепляет их к заявке.
Проблема в том, что если в названии вложения, приблизительно, больше 40 символов (вместе с расширением), то слетает кодировка в названии вложения прикрепляемое к заявке.
Выглядит это примерно так.
`- Added attachment '=?windows-1251?B?0l83NzA3MDgzODkzXzQwOTExODEwNDAwMDIwMDAyMDUyXzI3NS55MDkudHh0?=' to Event with id 12538666.`

Если я беру это вложение и разбиваю название на 2 маленьких - то названия вложений не "слетают"

`- Added attachment '40911810400020002052_275.y09.txt' to Event with id 12538666.`
`- Added attachment 'Ð¢_7707083893.y09.txt' to Event with id 12538666.`

Сам код большой, поэтому прикладываю часть, в которой определяется названия вложений

```
for _, ATT in ipairs(MBOX:attachments(MSG)) do
        local FILE, DESC, DATA, DATA_ERR
        FILE = MBOX:attachment_filename(ATT)
        if FILE and type(FILE) == "string" then
            FILE = imap.utf8_from_mime2(FILE)
        end
```

Просьба подсказать, как это можно исправить?

Дополнение информации

---

Нашел функцию по декодированию из base64. Обрезал сломаное название вложения и прогнал через функцию - название стало определяется корректно, но теперь получаю вот такую ошибку

Could not add attachment 'Ò_7707083893_40911810400020002052_275.y09.txt' to Event with id 12538736: Exception: ReaderException: The received request could not be parsed. org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x5f
at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@6abbb42e; line: 1, column: 60]. Status code: 400

Как я понял проблема в том, что сервер принимает только utf-8, а я пытаюсь передать в windows-1251

Answer (score 0):

Строка `0l83NzA3MDgzODkzXzQwOTExODEwNDAwMDIwMDAyMDUyXzI3NS55MDkudHh0` это строка `Т_7707083893_40911810400020002052_275.y09.txt`, закодированная как [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

О том, что строка закодирована говорят символы `=` в начале и конце строки.

Первая часть между вопросами (`windows-1251`) говорит, что после раскодированя нужно этот поток байтов воспринимать как текст в кодировке windows-1251.

Вторая часть (`B`), говорит, что используется base64.

А третья часть — это собственно закодированный текст.

Answer (score 0):

Решение первой части Вашей проблемы (как раскодировать строку) подробно описал Герман.

Решить вторую часть Вашей проблемы (перевести раскодированную строку из 1251 в UTF8) можно вызовом функции `win_to_utf8` из [этого Lua-модуля](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/44a88f64f9a497919db4ad8c28259a8f).